# SSL wildcard pattern not working when prefixing URL with "www."

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain

If I have a certificate which is issued to *.abc.dk, I can get to the site with for example vm.abc.dk fine (changes automatically to https://www.vm.abc.dk) but when I try to write www.vm.abc.dk I get the error SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN in Firefox and similar error in Chrome.

If I choose to proceed or add an exception, it is able to redirect to https://vm.abc.dk fine. Do I need to add a SAN to my certificate, or what is the reason that I can't connect instantly with www.vm.abc.dk?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a wildcard cert is only valid for anything at that sub-domain and no other lower sub-domain.

Ie. *.abc.dk is anything.abc.dk
But will not work with any.thing.abc.dk
For this you would need *.thing.abc.dk

Because you are requesting www.*.vm.abc.dk then the cert is not valid and is why you get the SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error.

You could add a SAN which would probably be best, unless someone else has a better idea.

Comment: I'm requesting www.vm.abc.dk, and not www.*.vm.abc.dk. Should *.vm.dk still not "cover" this? Or do you need to add a SAN to support the www prefix?

Comment: It is valid for *.abc.dk only not for www.vm.ABC.dk.

Answer (score 1):

You need a certificate which is valid for `vm.abc.dk` and `www.vm.abc.dk`.

- <del>So, if you want to go the wildcard way, get a cert including:</del>

  - <del>`*.abc.dk`</del>
  - <del>`*.*.abc.dk`</del>

  **Edit:** According to Steffen Ullrich in the comments, this is not possible. Thanks for the hint!
- or, if this is cheaper or there aren't that many subdomains involved, put all of them into the `Subject Alternative Name` field.

Comment: There can only be a single wildcard and this only matches the leftmost label. Thus `*.abc.dk` is possible, `*.*.abc.dk` or `www.*.abc.dk` are not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your comment. This isn't forbidden in the corresponding RFC, so technically this should be possible, but it's not supported by the browsers, right?

Comment: RFC 2818 (HTTP-TLS) is not specific, But in [RFC 6125 6.4.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#page-27) it says:  "The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
       which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
       left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net).". Apart from that CA/Browser forum is relevant for the implementation in the browsers and what kind of certificates gets issued.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks! I've incorporated these information into my answer.